# Excel added quotation marks to csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, row

Good morning,
I was working with a CSV file in Excel. I usually use python for reading, but I had to perform a very quick operation (add a few rows), so I decided to do it via Excel.

Once I saved the CSV however my read script on python was not working. I then noticed that extra quotes had been added.

from:

```
"16/09/20 11:50:00";"26.3";"26.6";"60.6";"60.9";"2357.0";"2438.0"
```

to:

```
"16/09/20 11:50:00;""26.3"";""26.6"";""60.6"";""60.9"";""2357.0"";""2438.0"""
```

Is there any way to restore the csv to its original format?

Comment: did your original excel file had the values quoted in double-quotes? I just tried and added your sample data with quotes, in turn excel added additional set of quotes to escape double-quote.   But, in my case it only happens to the data that I added with the quotes and not to the data that didn't had any quotes. Have you tried to find/replace the double quotes in your excel?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring it back to its original format you can use find and replace.
For example you can replace **""** with just **"**.
Hopefully this helps.
Here's how to do it:

1. Windows: Ctrl H
2. Mac: hold "shift" + "command" + "H" on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

bad_csv = open('your_bad_csv', "r")
lines = bad_csv.readlines()

good_csv = open('your_target_good.csv', 'w')

for line in lines:
    new_line = re.sub('""', '"', line[1:-1])
    new_line = '"' + re.sub(';', '";', new_line, count=1)
    good_csv.write(f"{new_line}\n")
    
bad_csv.close()
good_csv.close()
```

Comment: This method adds additional ''" to the file.

Comment: sorry about giving you bad code.  updated my answer.